# Does the analogous saying: "matter is essentially 'condensed' energy" have any merit?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, mass-energy, matter

Einstein in his derivation of special relativity came upon the equivalence of energy and matter, and given the right circumstances, the relation can go either way - matter can become energy, and energy can become matter - right?

So my question relates to the second process - energy becoming matter.

While I know energy does not literally *condense* into matter in the sense that steam condenses into water, by analogy does the (rather loose) saying:

> "matter is essentially condensed energy"

have any merit?

Comment: I'm not sure what "condensed" is really supposed to mean in this context, so I don't particularly like the saying, as it might confuse people who try to read too much into that word. However, any physicist would understand what concept the saying was referring to.

Comment: Energy is the ability to perform work and that is the correct technical definition. That ability is not perfect. It is limited by thermodynamics, which inevitably comes into play when we are talking about matter. The key properties of energy can be discussed perfectly on their own by using energy conservation and Noether's theorem, which links it to time translation invariance on a single page, but if we want to talk about matter in detail, we need an entire library of material. To link matter and energy on such a naive level completely misunderstands reality. I would not teach it that way.

Comment: Furthermore, "matter is essentially condensed energy" suggests that there is such a thing as "energy" independent of the form that it takes. Matter is a *form* of energy, rather than matter being "made of" energy. Energy is a category of things, not a thing itself.

Comment: Just say instead that mass (not matter, there is a difference) is energy, full stop. And follow up by saying that this does mean that, for example, an object is a tiny bit heavier when it is spinning, or when its temperature increases. It just happens to be true that most of the energy/mass in solid objects does not come from familiar heat or spinning, but rather from the subatomic forces that bind them together. But the idea is not that one can do some trick to exchange energy for mass, it is that they are literally the exact same thing.

Comment: Indeed the mass of a nucleon is mostly the "confined" interaction energies of the quark and gluon constituents and not the summed masses of those constituents.